# Estimate extreme eigenvalues with CG

Tags: linear-algebra, conjugate-gradient, eigenvalues

CG may be used to estimate the extremal eigenvalues of a SPD matrix (by computing eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrix associated with the Lanczos algorithm). After a few iterations the largest eigenvalue is generally well approximated whereas the smallest is generally overestimated.

Is there a way to have some estimate of the quality of those approximate eigenvalues?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4725) from [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/365/estimation-of-condition-numbers-for-very-large-matrices).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "quality" of the approximation?

Comment: @JackPoulson - I'm okay with letting this stand as a separate question, do you mind moving your comment to an answer?

Comment: I would like to have some lower and upper bounds on the approximation I get. I'll have a look to the paper, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

This question is very related to [another SE question on condition number estimates](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/365/20688) which contains relevant materials.

As @Jack_Poulson mentioned, the following paper contains a detailed discussion on the asked topic:

- [J. Kuczyński and H. Woźniakowski, "Estimating the Largest Eigenvalue by the Power and Lanczos Algorithms with a Random Start," *SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl.*, vol. 13, no. 4, pp. 1094–1122](https://doi.org/10.1137/0613066). Downloadable version of a slightly different version of this paper [is available here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4725).