# Conjugate residual/gradient convergence checking in practice

Tags: finite-element, iterative-method, convergence, conjugate-gradient

Let's say we want to solve $Ax=b$ ($A$ symmetric positive /semi/definite) with the conjugate residual/gradient method. $A$ comes from FEM where the mesh is being refined. The exact solution is $x_*$ and the approximate solution after $m$ iterations is $x_m$. Say that the initial guess is $x_0=0$.

We have that
$$\varepsilon=\left(\frac{(x_*-x_m, A(x_*-x_m))}{(x_*-x_m, A(x_*-x_m))}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{(A^{1/2}(x_*-x_m), A^{1/2}(x_*-x_m))}{(A^{1/2}(x_*-x_m), A^{1/2}(x_*-x_m))}\right)^{1/2}\le2\left(\frac{\sqrt{\kappa}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa}+1}\right)^m$$
with $\kappa$ being the condition number of $A$. But how can I calculate or estimate this in practice? I don't have $x_*$, all I have is $x_m$ and thus $r_m=b-Ax_m$. Sure, I can calculate
\begin{align}
\tilde{\varepsilon}=\left(\frac{(r_m,r_m)}{(r_0,r_0)}\right)^{1/2}&=\left(\frac{(b-Ax_m,b-Ax_m)}{(b-Ax_0,b-Ax_0)}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{(b-Ax_m,b-Ax_m)}{(b-Ax_0,b-Ax_0)}\right)^{1/2} \\
&=\left(\frac{(A(x_*-x_m),A(x_*-x_m))}{(A(x_*-x_0),A(x_*-x_0))}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{(A(x_*-x_m),A(x_*-x_m))}{(b,b)}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
but then what? For a fix $A$ I think I'll still have the same asymptotic decrease in the $A$-norm when using $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ as stopping criterion, that is $\left(\frac{\sqrt{\kappa}-1}{\sqrt{\kappa}+1}\right)^m$, so if I continue until $\tilde{\varepsilon}<\tilde{\varepsilon}_{\mathrm{max}}$ then the number of iterations needed are $m=c\sqrt{\kappa}$. But even so, $c$ depends on $A$! That means my iteration count could behave oddly if I'm using the algorithm for different matrices $A$ (corresponding to a mesh that has been refined a different number of times), does it not? Using $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ might not give the wanted $\sqrt{\kappa}$ growth of the iteration count. (Now, I'm not sure why $\varepsilon$ is a better stopping criterion than $\tilde{\varepsilon}$, but using one for theory and the other for implementation without understanding how they're connected feels very immoral.)

Comment: The intermediate steps in the CG algorithm are related to the Lanczos process, from which you can extract eigenvalue estimates; you can use those to approximate the condition number. [This answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-can-i-estimate-the-condition-number-of-a-large-sparse-matrix-using-petsc) shows how to do it with PETSc and section 3.1 of [this](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/aztecoo/AztecOOUserGuide.pdf) for Trilinos.

Comment: Maybe this answer is relevant, maybe it's not. Care to elaborate (a lot)?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear -- provided I understood you correctly, you're looking for a good stopping criterion for CG. You have some bounds for the error of CG, but these either use the condition number or the exact solution of the system, neither of which you know. It looked like you wanted to use the norm of the residual to decide; I'm suggesting that you can instead approximate the condition number without much more work and use that to decide whether or not to stop the iteration.

Comment: So using residuals ($\tilde{\varepsilon}$) will not necesarily give an iteration count that increases as $\sqrt{\kappa}$? Is it likely that it will be almost $\sqrt{\kappa}$ or can it be anything? Since it seems a lot of people who use FEM use $\varepsilon$ theoretically and then $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ in the implementation it seems they believe the latter should give approximately $\sqrt{\kappa}$ as well.